# Laravel вызвать контроллер в анонимной функции в роутинге

Tags: php, laravel

В документации полно примеров как вызвать метод контроллера для обработки конкретного url. Например:

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')
```

Но что делать, если контроллер нужно вызвать после проверки параметров в анонимной функции?

```
Route::get('{rubric}/{article?}', function($rubric, $article = null){
    if(is_null($article)){
        Controller::call('BlogController@main'); //Не работает
    } else{
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: `App::call('App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@main');` - ?

Comment: А зачем такие извращения?

Comment: Проверяй параметры непосредственно в контроллере, а еще лучше, если проверки объемные, сделай `middleware` и добавь его к роуту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал использовать для этой цели редирект:

```
Route::get('{rubric}/{article?}', function($rubric, $article = null){
    if (is_null($article)) {
        return redirect(action('BlogController@main'));
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему примеру кода, вам подойдет решение в виде двух записей в файле с маршрутами:

```
Route::get('{rubric}/{article}', function($rubric, $article){
   // ...
});
Route::get('{rubric}', 'BlogController@main');
```

Тогда первый маршрут останется замыканием и обработкой одной статьи, а второй маршрут отработает страницу всей рубрики.

Comment: Это решение логичное, но неужели никак нельзя вызвать метод контроллера из роутинга?

Comment: Отвечу вопросом на вопрос: а зачем вам вызывать отдельный метод контроллера внутри замыкания?

У самого возникала такая необходимость, но в итоге это приведёт к запутанности кода и сложности дальнейшей поддержки.

Нет, конечно, если интересует чисто техническая возможность так сделать, то вот вам решение:
`(new App\Http\Controllers\BlogController())->main()`
но я так делать не советую.